# rails 3.2 with ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Guys I have the following action on my controller to send emails to my users.

```
def email_all_users
    User.all.each do |u|
    if !u.information.nil?
        if !u.information.business
            UserMailer.candidate_email(u).deliver
        else 
                UserMailer.business_email(u).deliver
        end
    else
            UserMailer.no_info_email(u).deliver
    end
  end
  redirect_to "/users/#{current_user.id}",  :flash => { :success => "Los correos fueron enviados" }
end
```

And here is the link in my view

```
<%= link_to "Enviar Correos".html_safe, {:controller => "users", :action => "email_all_users"}, :method => "get",  :id => "email_users", :html =>  {:style => "color:#FAA732;" }, :remote => true %>
<span id="loading" style="color:rgb(41, 160, 41);display:none;"><i class="icon-spinner icon-spin"></i> Enviando</span>
<span id="send" style="color:rgb(41, 160, 41);display:none;"><i class="icon-ok-circle"></i> Enviado!</span>
```

I create this file email_all_users.js.erb with this content

```
$('#email_users').hide();
$('#email_users').ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#loading').show();
});
$('#email_users').ajaxComplete(function() {
   $('#loading')..hide();
   $('#send')..show();
});
```

As you can see after click in the link I want hide the link and show and image that I have in my loading span (loading is the id), then when the action finish I want to hide the loading and show my send span (send is the id of the span).

What I'm doing wrong because when I click the app send the emails, but does not hide the link and don't show the loading and the send.

Thanks in advance for your help

SOLUTION

---

I move my email_all_users.js.erb to my assets folder and I changed it like this:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#email_users').hide();
    $('#loading').show();
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
    $('#send').show();
});
```

Problem solve.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Those ajax calls need to go into a regular js file, not as a response to the action. When this code is getting called the ajax reques has already completed.